# Turning an Int into a String

Tags: swift, string, int

I'm pretty new to swift (and programming altogether). I'm trying to convert an Int into a String. I've tried using switch statements but every time I use them, it never changes to the String (AKA it prints the number 4) An example of what I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
class Birthday(_ month: Int, _ day:Int, _ year:Int) -> String{
    //Here is where I'd like to turn my month into April

    Return (month)
}

let example = Birthday()

example(4,15,1988)
```

Comment: `return ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"][month - 1]`

Comment: @vacawama Why not use `DateFormatter monthSymbols`?

Comment: @rmaddy, indeed that is a good idea.  Understanding how my comment works would also be useful for a beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really just want to get a month name from a month number, you can do the following:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
let monthName = formatter.monthSymbols[month - 1] // Assuming 1 means January
```

But since you are passing in a month, day, and year, you presumably want to create a `Date` and then you want to format that `Date` into a `String.

Create a `Date` using `Calendar` and `DateComponents`.

```
let date = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day))
```

Then you format the `Date` into a `String` using `DateFormatter`.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .long // choose a desired style
formatter.timeStyle = .none
let string = formatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: Note that `DateFormatter` is provided by the Foundation framework, so you'll need `import Foundation` if you don't already have an `import UIKit` or `import Cocoa`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dictionary` which maps objects to each other. For example, a months dictionary could look like:

```
let months: [Int:String] = [1:"January", 2:"February",...]
return months[4] // returns "April"
```

Comment: Do not do this. `DateFormatter` already provides a localized array of month names.

Comment: @rmaddy sure, but it's clear based on the question that they're not understanding the concept of manipulating an input value to something else. `DateFormatter` works for the specific example but if they come upon another situation like this where this isn't a premade array, they'll have an idea of what they can do instead.

Comment: BTW - why use a dictionary for this? Why not a simple array?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to get you started would be a method that takes an integer and return your month string.

```
func numberToMonth(number: Int) -> String {

    guard number > 0, number < 13 else { return "" }
    return DateFormatter().monthSymbols[number-1]
}
```

Comment: Do not do this. `DateFormatter` already provides localized names for all of the months.

Comment: Umm, this is now mostly redundant because of @rmaddy's answer.  Besides, how is this returning an optional instead of crashing if the index is out of range?